# Cannot map HKU registry hive with powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

I have a question regarding deleting from registry key HKU (HKEY_USERS). If I run this with powershell, I get an error:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $inputPC -ScriptBlock { Remove-Item -Path 'HKU:\S-1-5-25\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce'}
```

The error:

```
Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'HKU' does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKU:String) [Remove-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : clt64792
```

But if for `HKU:` I exchange it for example to `HKLM:` it works and deletes the registry key, how can I access the `HKU`? I have tried different approaches to delete registry keys and all work the same, but none of them maps the HKU registry key.

Comment: Thre is no HKU drive set by default in PowerShell. Try adding this in the script block: New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS

Comment: Have tried, also could not find it.

Comment: It works fine here. Stating the obvious but, are you really creating the drive inside your remote session?

ie. *$testing = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $inputPC -ScriptBlock { New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -
Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS; Get-Item HKU:\S-1-5-25 }*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default, only the following PowerShell drives referencing registry locations are defined:

```bsh
PS> Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                                           CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                                                           ---------------
HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER                                                                                                             
HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
```

That is, **only drives `HKCU:` and `HKLM:` exist by default**.

---

In order to access keys in the `HKEY_USERS` hive, you have two options:

- **Define a custom `HKU` PowerShell drive** using [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive), as [theadzik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947738/theadzik) suggests in a comment, though that may not be worth it (in your case, you'll have to do that *inside the script block* passed to `Invoke-Command`):

```
# Define drive HKU:
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS
# Now you can use HKU:\... paths
```

- **Use provider prefix `registry::` with the native registry path**, which is **simpler for ad-hoc use**:

```
# E.g.
Get-ChildItem registry::HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT
```

In the context of your command:

```bsh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $inputPC -ScriptBlock { 
  Remove-Item 'registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-25\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce'
}
```