# Issue with script to detect if software is installed in Local AppData

Tags: powershell

I created a script which should check if Google Chrome is installed in a users Local AppData folder. In order to do that, it checks if the registry key in HKEY_USERS\UserSID\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome is there.

On a Test VM, I installed Google Chrome with two test users. When going manually to the above path, I can see the Google Chrome folder exists. However, when running the script below, it says that the registry key cannot be found. What am I missing?

```
 $registryPath = "HKU:\*\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome"
    
    
    $outputFile = "\\FileShare\NewFolder\Chrome.txt"
    
    if (Test-Path $registryPath) {
        $InstallLocation = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name InstallLocation).InstallLocation
        $displayVersion = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name DisplayVersion).DisplayVersion
        
    
        $output = "$($env:COMPUTERNAME), $InstallLocation, $displayVersion, $(Get-Date -Format ""dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"")"
        $output | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputFile
    
        Write-Host "Checking ready."
    } else {
        #Registry key not found
        Write-Error "Can't find the registry"
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no PS drive called `HKU:`.. The only predefined drives for the registry are `HKCU:` (HKEY_CURRENT_USER) and `HKLM:` (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE). To get info for the HKEY_USERS hive you need to use `"Registry::HKEY_USERS\*\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome"` and iterate over the results. For access you need to run as ADmin as well.

Comment: Thanks @Theo !
I used the above and ran the script manually with Admin permissions and the output is written in the text file.

Is it possible to use this script in a GPO to let it check all workstations? If yes, would I have to add something in my script or how could I get it done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot map HKU registry hive with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059948/cannot-map-hku-registry-hive-with-powershell)